# How can I invoke `EditorExtensions.EditorFor` in my HtmlHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I use different Models in my CreateView, all inherit from BaseModel. To call the right EditorFor I have created a HtmlHelper that gets the Model and the actual property. But I don´t know how to invoke it.

BaseModel:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    protected IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> PropertyInfoCache { get; set; }
    protected IEnumerable<EnumeratedProperty> EnumeratedPropertyCache { get; set; }
    protected BaseModel()
    {
        PropertyInfoCache = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        EnumeratedPropertyCache = PropertyInfoCache.Select(p=> new EnumeratedProperty(p.Name,p.GetType()));
    }
    public IEnumerable<EnumeratedProperty> EnumerateProperties()
    {
        return EnumeratedPropertyCache;
    }
    public object GetPropertyValue(string PropertyName)
    {
        var property = PropertyInfoCache.SingleOrDefault(i=>i.Name==PropertyName);
        if(property!=null)
            return property.GetValue(this,null);
        return null;
    }
}

public class EnumeratedProperty
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Type Type { get; private set; }
    public EnumeratedProperty(string PropertyName, Type PropertyType)
    {
        this.Name = PropertyName;
        this.Type = PropertyType;
    }
}
```

in my View:

```
@foreach (var property in Model.EnumerateProperties())
{
    @Html.EditorForProperty(Model,property);
}
```

HtmlHelper:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static MvcHtmlString EditorForProperty(this HtmlHelper html, BaseModel Model, EnumeratedProperty property)
    {
        // creates an error: The type arguments for method 'EditorFor' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
        return System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(html, Model => Model.GetPropertyValue(property.Name) );
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? I am afraid that you are reinventing some wheels. Could you please state your original intent with having this BaseModel class?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I´m creating a shop with, lets say lamps, I use a basemodel for the lamps with price etc and a bunch of inherit models with special params. Now I have created a CreateView with the BaseModel and loop through my parameters but the default EditorFor don´t recorgnise my values correct, he needs the type.

Comment: so essentially you want to convert a list of objects in a dictionary to get MVC to recognize them as properties...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EditorFor recognizes the type of an object, so what you would want to do is extract the type from the value in the EnumeratedProperty class, instead of passing the class directly, and pass in the value from it too.

Comment: Your code above has html .. ? .. ? where the editorfor extension is used... what have you tried?  Could you post a sample of that?

Comment: edited my post with my try to invoke the methode but i don´t know how to define the type explicite in this methode :-(

Comment: OK, so I see your dilemma now, and based on the existing EditorFor, you may not be able to do it.  When you use the lambda, it does two things: define the process to update the model when the form is posted back, and extract the value from the object.  This is why it often uses explicit properties within models.