# Refactor Control Pattern in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The following code snippet effectively represents items in a large form. My objective is to refactor it down.

```
<div class="span3">
<ul style="list-style-type: none">
    <li><b>Description</b></li>
    <li>
        <textarea style="width: 100%;" rows="4">@Model.Item.Description</textarea>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="span3">
<ul style="list-style-type: none">
    <li><b>Truck</b></li>
    <li>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Item.ShippingTruckId, new SelectList(Model.ShippingTrucks, "Id", "Truck"))
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="span3">
<ul style="list-style-type: none">
    <li><b>Cost</b></li>
    <li>
        <input value="@Model.Item.Cost"/>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Two approaches I've considered is a partial view and an HTML helper. Ultimately though, how do a pair those down into a smaller easier to maange segment. I'm generally either going to have that same structure with either an input, a text area, a drop down, or in some cases a label. Is there another, superior, approach I haven't thought of, or any inherent disadvantages/advantages/challenges to one I've mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reflection you can read all the properties and EditorFor to create the elements:

[Example for Reflection I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493354/how-can-i-get-my-properties-from-a-model-into-my-view-with-a-foreach)
[Example for reflection II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702300/c-sharp-reflection-use-variable-as-object-var)

With first example:

```
@foreach (var property in Model.EnumerateProperties())
{
    <div class="span3">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none">
        <li><b>@Html.LabelForProperty(Model,property);</b></li>
        <li>
            @Html.EditorForProperty(Model,property);
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
}
```

And [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655930/asp-net-mvc-4-editor-template-for-basic-types) you can see how to use editor template for diferent type of property or use UIHint.

**Edit for this comment:**: "How do you handle the dropdownlists this way?"

in this case I can think of a solution, but a bit complex. you can on the property put an attribute, something like:

```
[ItPropertyHaveAList("PropertyWithListList")]
public int PropertyWithListId { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PropertyWithListList { get; set; }
```

then the extension `EditorForProperty` you can detect if the property has this attribute [like this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7864693/138071):

```
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "First name must be between 5 and 20 characters")]
public string FirstName {get;set;}

StringLengthAttribute strLenAttr = 
  typeof(Person).GetProperty("FirstName").GetCustomAttributes(
  typeof(StringLengthAttribute), false).Cast<StringLengthAttribute>().Single();


int maxLen = strLenAttr.MaximumLength;
```

In this attribute you put the method from list data to create a dropdownlists. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11499055/138071) response to see how create template for dropdownlists.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and very helpful. 

Before I accept, I have one question - How do you handle the dropdownlists this way?